# Is there a more efficient way to refactor the iteration of the hash on ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration, key, numeric

I have a iteration here:

```
container = []
summary_data.each do |_index, data|
  container << data
end
```

The structure of the `summary_data` is listed below:

```
summary_data = {
  "1" => { orders: { fees: '25.00' } },
  "3" => { orders: { fees: '30.00' } },
  "6" => { orders: { fees: '45.00' } }
}
```

I want to remove the numeric key, e.g., "1", "3".

And I expect to get the following `container`:

```
[
  {
    "orders": {
      "fees": "25.00"
    }
  },
  {
    "orders": {
      "fees": "30.00"
    }
  },
  {
    "orders": {
      "fees": "45.00"
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a more efficient way to refactor the code above?

Appreciate for any help.

Comment: @SimpleLime oops, I’ve overlooked the colons :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Hash#values` method, like this:

```
container = summary_data.values
```

Answer (score 1):

If the inner hashes all have the same structure, the only interesting information are the fees:

```
summary_data.values.map{|h| h[:orders][:fees] }
# => ["25.00", "30.00", "45.00"]
```

If you want to do some calculations with those fees, you could convert them to numbers:

```
summary_data.values.map{|h| h[:orders][:fees].to_f }
# => [25.0, 30.0, 45.0]
```

It might be even better to work with cents as integers to avoid any floating point error:

```
summary_data.values.map{|h| (h[:orders][:fees].to_f * 100).round }
=> [2500, 3000, 4500]
```

Comment: I suggest you not use `dig` here, instead, use the old-fashioned `h[:orders][:fees]`. We know that `h[:orders]` should not be `nil`. If it is, `nil[:fees]` will raise an exception, the behavior we want. By contrast, the use of `dig` will just return `nil`, without complaint. Similarly, `h.dig(:orders, :fees).to_f` will return `0.0` if `to_f`'s receiver is `nil`; again, not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

You need an array having values of provided hash. You can get by values method directly.
`summary_data.values`